# vb.net for all numericUpDown GotFocus

Tags: vb.net, numericupdown

In vb.net I would like to set all numericUpDown (NUD) controls to select their value when they receive focus, like a text box does.

Do I need to write a GotFocus handler for each NUD?

Ta

EDI: I know I can use `widthBox.Select(0, widthBox.ToString().Length)` to do the selection I just need to be able to apply this to all NUD GotFocus events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Project> Add New Item> CustomControl (with name customUpDown).

In solution explorer select view all files and find and open customUpDown.Designer.vb change the line `Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Control1` to `Inherits System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown` and save.

View code on the file customUpDown.vb file and add

```
Private Sub 
customUpDown_GotFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles_
Me.GotFocus 
Me.Select(0, Me.ToString().Length) 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could inherit your own control from a NumericUpDown that has the desired behavior, and use that instead.

Comment: That sounds tidy, how do I do that? can you point me int he direction a tutorial or something? Im very much a vb noob, only using it to throw together a quick interface for testing an embedded C system's comms.